# Extraction APK : what are .png@ files?

Tags: java, android, apk, decompiling

I would like to extract the images from an android game.

Firstly, I took the APK on my windows 10 laptop then I extracted the files (rename files.apk to files.apk.zip and extracted it with 7zip).
Inside my folders I got many .png files but I get an error when I try to open one. Each .png file has another file with the same name but with .png@. Some even have 2 otherfiles with them : one with .skel (can't open this one too) and .atlas (I can open it with notepad):

[image]

Did I make mistakes? What can I do to "repair" all these png files?
Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are authorised to do so then you can `apktool`.

Its easy to use and may that @png files will be converted to some meaningful resource.

```
    Installation for Apktool
Windows:
Download Windows wrapper script (Right click, Save Link As apktool.bat)
Download apktool-2 (find newest here)
Rename downloaded jar to apktool.jar
Move both files (apktool.jar & apktool.bat) to your Windows directory (Usually C://Windows)
If you do not have access to C://Windows, you may place the two files anywhere then add that directory to your Environment Variables System PATH variable.
Try running apktool via command prompt
```

[Link](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/)

Comment: I followed your advice, and changed the screen in my post. Tell me what do you think about it!